# How to close chrome tab using jquery

Tags: jquery

We open a new Chrome tab, check certain conditions, and try to turn it off if it doesn't match.

ex)
windows open ("http://Yahoo.co.kr")

if(a != null) {windows close ?}

If the "a" condition is not null, I'm trying to turn off the Yahoo tab. Which command should I use to close it?

Answer (score 1):

This **doesn't work directly in Stackoverflow**, but feel free to try it somewhere else.

Also, **no need for jQuery**.

```js
let newwin = null;
let is_open = false;

let a = 'not null';

document.querySelector('button#open').addEventListener('click', function()
{
  if (!is_open)
  {
    newwin = open('https://yahoo.co.kr');
    is_open = true;
  }
});

document.querySelector('button#close').addEventListener('click', function()
{
  if (a != null && is_open)
  {
    newwin.close();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in StackOverflow, for some reason. But try it in the console